# How to Install GoLang on Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS: Cannot Execute Binary File

Tags: server, 20.04, golang

I'm trying to install Golang on my raspberry pi running ubuntu server 20.04LTS and am having a lot of trouble. I could probably use advice on how to make sure I undo and uninstall any changes I made while attempting to install go-lang via snap and apt-get.
I have successfully installed the package from `tar.gz` found at `go.dev`  into the correct location `/usr/local/`  But no matter how many instructions I follow on exporting the path I always get this same error.

[image]

I have cleared out my path in order to prep for getting help

[image]

And I have extracted /go from the `go.dev` `tar.gz` file

[image]

Please I really could use some help with the appropriate installation procedure.

What is the correct method? `snap` or `apt-get`?

How are the variables actually supposed to be set?

How do I make sure I uninstall everything I did wrong and reinstall the right way ?

I have tried several times to compile it manually by unzipping from tar.gz but even when I try running `./go/bin/go` directly I still get the error `-bash: ./go/bin/go: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`

two commands I ran troubleshooting that Im not sure how to undo.. or if i need to.

`sudo update-alternatives --set go /usr/local/go/bin/go`

`sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/go" "go" "/usr/local/go/bin/go" 0`

Comment: 20.04 LTS is the version I am running thank you for helping me clarify.

Comment: It is 20.04 LTS

Comment: Which guide do you follow? Why do you have `go` in `/usr/local/go/bin/go`? What is the output of `file /usr/local/go/bin/go`? What is the output of `arch`? What was wrong with official [deb-packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=bin%2Fgo)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove wrongly manually installed Go executable by

```
sudo rm /usr/local/go/bin/go
```

and then install normal one from [official repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=bin%2Fgo) by:

```
sudo apt-get install golang-go
```